# How to disable Unity keyboard shortcut for Spread mode

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, eclipse

I got a very weird problem. My developer laptop runs Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity. As a Java developer I'm using eclipse which whose shortcuts conflicts with the shortcuts of Unity.

The problem shortcuts is the one for the Spread mode. It is set to Super + W (in my case Windows + W) what is ok for me so far. The real problem is that Spread mode is also triggered when pressing Shift + Alt + Up. Unfortunately this shortcut is already used by eclipse but is somehow overwritten by Unity.

I've already read a lot about how to disable and change the shortcuts for unity using the CompizConfig Settings Manager. But I couldn't manage to disable the Shift + Alt + Up combo.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is set in the "Scale" plugin in the CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Go to the settings for "Scale" under "Window Management," and you'll see an option for "Initiate Window Picker" under bindings.  Just click on the edit icon for that and disable it.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer above does not seem to work on Ubuntu 11.10 - at least I could not find the CompizConfig. Instead I install gconf-editor and found the following option:

```
/apps/compiz-1/plugins/scale/screen0/options/initiate_key
```